# Windows Phone 8 Page Orientation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I detect orientation when the page has been loaded or while the page is loading? I implemented `OrientationChanged` method. But when I set the first page as landscape, the second page doesnt trigger this method. Page is in landscape mode but UI is not. I mean page orientation is ok, but musnt `OrientationChanged` be triggered? I change the appearance of the UI objects in this method. If it is not triggered, UI will shown like in portrait mode.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        SwitchPanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 100, 250, 0);
        StatusPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }
    else
    {
        SwitchPanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 100, 12, 0);
        StatusPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put your code in a distinct method, and call this method both from the `OrientationChanged` and `Loaded` events:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SetOrientation(this.Orientation);
}

private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SetOrientation(e.Orientation);
}

private void SetOrientation(PageOrientation orientation)
{
    if (orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape || orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        SwitchPanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 100, 250, 0);
        StatusPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }
    else
    {
        SwitchPanel.Margin = new Thickness(12, 100, 12, 0);
        StatusPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
}
```

Comment: its very bad way to solve it. something must be offered us about this. anyway, I have typed codes and worked. because of some ui delay, i removed `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` code line that you gave. I put it into page constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wire up the event to the event handler? You should have something similar to the following in your constructor....

```
this.OrientationChanged += PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged;
```

Comment: there is no reason to add this line into constructor. because I have declared `OrientationChanged` event in xaml. visual studio automatically creates it when you try double-click event list item in properties window to implement anyone of them

Comment: Understood. This wasn't evident in the code you provided.

FYI, this code actually does exist... but you don't see it because it's in the normally hidden partial class (which contains all the generated code) that is associated with the one that you actually write in. You wouldn't know it's there unless you actually went looking for it.

So your answer to my question was actually, "yes".  :)

@KooKiz's answer should be correct.

Comment: Of course I know that compiler creates this line for me. But I just said for my actual MainPage.cs file :) not the compiled one